# Optimizing the CUDA kernel with stencil pattern

Tags: c++, cuda

In the process of writing a program for processing digital images, I wrote a CUDA kernel that runs slowly. The code is given below:

```
__global__ void Kernel ( int* inputArray, float* outputArray, float3* const col_image, int height, int width, int kc2 ) {
    float G, h;
    float fx[3];
    float fy[3];
    float g[2][2];
    float k10 = 0.0;
    float k11 = 0.0;
    float k12 = 0.0;
    float k20 = 0.0;
    float k21 = 0.0;
    float k22 = 0.0;
    float k30 = 0.0;
    float k31 = 0.0;
    float k32 = 0.0;

    int xIndex = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int yIndex = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if ((xIndex < width - kc2/2) && (xIndex >= kc2/2) && (yIndex < height - kc2/2) && (yIndex >= kc2/2))
    {
        int idx0 = yIndex * width + xIndex;
        if (inputArray[idx0] > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < kc2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < kc2; j++)
                {
                    int idx1 = (yIndex + i - kc2/2) * width + (xIndex + j - kc2/2);
                    float3 rgb = col_image[idx1];
                    k10 = k10 + constMat1[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.x;
                    k11 = k11 + constMat1[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.y;
                    k12 = k12 + constMat1[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.z;

                    k20 = k20 + constMat2[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.x;
                    k21 = k21 + constMat2[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.y;
                    k22 = k22 + constMat2[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.z;

                    k30 = k30 + constMat3[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.x;
                    k31 = k31 + constMat3[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.y;
                    k32 = k32 + constMat3[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.z;
                }
            }
            fx[0] = kc2 * (k30 - k20);
            fx[1] = kc2 * (k31 - k21);
            fx[2] = kc2 * (k32 - k22);
            fy[0] = kc2 * (k10 - k20);
            fy[1] = kc2 * (k11 - k21);
            fy[2] = kc2 * (k12 - k22);

            g[0][0] = fx[0] * fx[0] + fx[1] * fx[1] + fx[2] * fx[2];
            g[0][1] = fx[0] * fy[0] + fx[1] * fy[1] + fx[2] * fy[2];
            g[1][0] = g[0][1];
            g[1][1] = fy[0] * fy[0] + fy[1] * fy[1] + fy[2] * fy[2]
            G = g[0][0] * g[1][1] - g[0][1] * g[1][0];
            h = g[0][0] + g[1][1];

            // Output
            int idx2 = (yIndex - kc2/2) * (width - kc2) + (xIndex - kc2/2);
            outputArray[idx2] = (h * h) / G;
        }
    }
}
```

Here some (non-negative) values of *inputArray* are processed. The array *col-image* contains color components in the RGB model. If the value of *inputArray* satisfies the condition, then we compute the special coefficients k_{ij} in a neighborhood of kc2 on kc2 with center at the considered point (the value of kc2 is either 3 or 5). The values of *constMat[1,2,3]* are stored in the device's constant memory:

```
__device__ __constant__ float constMat[];
```

Then we calculate the characteristics *fx, fy, g_{ij}, h, G* and write the resulting value in the corresponding cell of *outputArray*.

Importantly, all the data specified is stored in global memory, and the fact that the input array can be large enough (about 40 million points). All this directly affects the speed of the kernel.

How do we speed up the execution of this kernel (any techniques are welcome: use of shared memory / textures, use of stencil templates, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would call a "standard" usage of shared memory to buffer a block of `col_image` for use (and reuse) by the threadblock would be a "standard" suggestion here.

According to my tests, it seems to offer a substantial improvement.  Since you have not provided a complete code, or any sort of data set or results verification, I will skip all those also.  What follows then is a not-really-tested implementation of shared memory into your existing code, to "buffer" a (threadblockwidth + kc2)*(threadblockheight+kc2) "patch" of the `col_image` input data into a shared memory buffer.  Thereafter, during the double-nested for-loops, the data is read out of the shared memory buffer.

A 2D shared memory stencil operation like this is an exercise in indexing as well as an exercise in handling edge cases.  Your code is somewhat simpler in that we need only consider the edges to the "right" and "downward" when considering the needed "halo" of data to be buffered into shared memory.

I have not attempted to verify that this code is perfect.  However it should give you a "roadmap" for how to implement a 2D shared memory buffer system, with some motivation for the effort: I witness about a ~5x speedup by doing so, although YMMV, and its entirely possible I've made a performance mistake.

Here's a worked example, showing the speedup on Pascal Titan X, CUDA 8.0.61, Linux:

```
$ cat t390.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

const int adim = 6000;
const int KC2 = 5;
const int thx = 32;
const int thy = 32;
__constant__ float constMat1[KC2*KC2];
__constant__ float constMat2[KC2*KC2];
__constant__ float constMat3[KC2*KC2];

__global__ void Kernel ( int* inputArray, float* outputArray, float3* const col_image, int height, int width, int kc2 ) {
    float G, h;
    float fx[3];
    float fy[3];
    float g[2][2];
    float k10 = 0.0;
    float k11 = 0.0;
    float k12 = 0.0;
    float k20 = 0.0;
    float k21 = 0.0;
    float k22 = 0.0;
    float k30 = 0.0;
    float k31 = 0.0;
    float k32 = 0.0;

    int xIndex = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int yIndex = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int idx0 = yIndex * width + xIndex;

#ifdef USE_SHARED
    __shared__ float3 s_col_image[thy+KC2][thx+KC2];
    int idx = xIndex;
    int idy = yIndex;
    int DATAHSIZE= height;
    int WSIZE = kc2;
    int DATAWSIZE = width;
    float3 *input = col_image;
    int BLKWSIZE = thx;
    int BLKHSIZE = thy;
    if ((idx < DATAHSIZE+WSIZE) && (idy < DATAWSIZE+WSIZE))
      s_col_image[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x]=input[idx0];
    if ((idx < DATAHSIZE+WSIZE) && (idy < DATAWSIZE) && (threadIdx.y > BLKWSIZE - WSIZE))
      s_col_image[threadIdx.y + (WSIZE-1)][threadIdx.x] = input[idx0+(WSIZE-1)*width];
    if ((idx < DATAHSIZE) && (idy < DATAWSIZE+WSIZE) && (threadIdx.x > BLKHSIZE - WSIZE))
      s_col_image[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x + (WSIZE-1)] = input[idx0+(WSIZE-1)];
    if ((idx < DATAHSIZE) && (idy < DATAWSIZE) && (threadIdx.x > BLKHSIZE - WSIZE) && (threadIdx.y > BLKWSIZE - WSIZE))
      s_col_image[threadIdx.y + (WSIZE-1)][threadIdx.x + (WSIZE-1)] = input[idx0+(WSIZE-1)*width + (WSIZE-1)];
    __syncthreads();
#endif


    if ((xIndex < width - kc2/2) && (xIndex >= kc2/2) && (yIndex < height - kc2/2) && (yIndex >= kc2/2))
    {
        if (inputArray[idx0] > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < kc2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < kc2; j++)
                {
#ifdef USE_SHARED
                    float3 rgb = s_col_image[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x];
#else
                    int idx1 = (yIndex + i - kc2/2) * width + (xIndex + j - kc2/2);
                    float3 rgb = col_image[idx1];
#endif
                    k10 = k10 + constMat1[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.x;
                    k11 = k11 + constMat1[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.y;
                    k12 = k12 + constMat1[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.z;

                    k20 = k20 + constMat2[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.x;
                    k21 = k21 + constMat2[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.y;
                    k22 = k22 + constMat2[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.z;

                    k30 = k30 + constMat3[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.x;
                    k31 = k31 + constMat3[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.y;
                    k32 = k32 + constMat3[i * kc2 + j] * rgb.z;
                }
            }
            fx[0] = kc2 * (k30 - k20);
            fx[1] = kc2 * (k31 - k21);
            fx[2] = kc2 * (k32 - k22);
            fy[0] = kc2 * (k10 - k20);
            fy[1] = kc2 * (k11 - k21);
            fy[2] = kc2 * (k12 - k22);

            g[0][0] = fx[0] * fx[0] + fx[1] * fx[1] + fx[2] * fx[2];
            g[0][1] = fx[0] * fy[0] + fx[1] * fy[1] + fx[2] * fy[2];
            g[1][0] = g[0][1];
            g[1][1] = fy[0] * fy[0] + fy[1] * fy[1] + fy[2] * fy[2]; // had a missing semicolon
            G = g[0][0] * g[1][1] - g[0][1] * g[1][0];
            h = g[0][0] + g[1][1];

            // Output
            int idx2 = (yIndex - kc2/2) * (width - kc2) + (xIndex - kc2/2); // possible indexing bug here
            outputArray[idx2] = (h * h) / G;
        }
    }
}

int main(){

  int *d_inputArray;
  int height = adim;
  int width = adim;
  float *d_outputArray;
  float3 *d_col_image;
  int kc2 = KC2;
  cudaMalloc(&d_inputArray, height*width*sizeof(int));
  cudaMemset(d_inputArray, 1, height*width*sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc(&d_col_image, (height+kc2)*(width+kc2)*sizeof(float3));
  cudaMalloc(&d_outputArray, height*width*sizeof(float));
  dim3 threads(thx,thy);
  dim3 blocks((adim+threads.x-1)/threads.x, (adim+threads.y-1)/threads.y);
  Kernel<<<blocks,threads>>>( d_inputArray, d_outputArray, d_col_image, height, width, kc2 );
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t390 t390.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t390
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ nvprof ./t390
==1473== NVPROF is profiling process 1473, command: ./t390
==1473== Profiling application: ./t390
==1473== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 97.29%  34.705ms         1  34.705ms  34.705ms  34.705ms  Kernel(int*, float*, float3*, int, int, int)
  2.71%  965.14us         1  965.14us  965.14us  965.14us  [CUDA memset]

==1473== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 88.29%  310.69ms         3  103.56ms  550.23us  309.46ms  cudaMalloc
  9.86%  34.712ms         1  34.712ms  34.712ms  34.712ms  cudaDeviceSynchronize
  1.05%  3.6801ms       364  10.110us     247ns  453.59us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
  0.70%  2.4483ms         4  612.07us  547.62us  682.25us  cuDeviceTotalMem
  0.08%  284.32us         4  71.079us  63.098us  79.616us  cuDeviceGetName
  0.01%  29.533us         1  29.533us  29.533us  29.533us  cudaMemset
  0.01%  21.189us         1  21.189us  21.189us  21.189us  cudaLaunch
  0.00%  5.2730us        12     439ns     253ns  1.1660us  cuDeviceGet
  0.00%  3.4710us         6     578ns     147ns  2.4820us  cudaSetupArgument
  0.00%  3.1090us         3  1.0360us     340ns  2.1660us  cuDeviceGetCount
  0.00%  1.0370us         1  1.0370us  1.0370us  1.0370us  cudaConfigureCall
ubuntu@titanxp-DiGiTS-Dev-Box:~/bobc/misc$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t390 t390.cu -DUSE_SHARED
ubuntu@titanxp-DiGiTS-Dev-Box:~/bobc/misc$ cuda-memcheck ./t390
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ nvprof ./t390
==1545== NVPROF is profiling process 1545, command: ./t390
==1545== Profiling application: ./t390
==1545== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 86.17%  5.4181ms         1  5.4181ms  5.4181ms  5.4181ms  Kernel(int*, float*, float3*, int, int, int)
 13.83%  869.94us         1  869.94us  869.94us  869.94us  [CUDA memset]

==1545== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 96.13%  297.15ms         3  99.050ms  555.80us  295.90ms  cudaMalloc
  1.76%  5.4281ms         1  5.4281ms  5.4281ms  5.4281ms  cudaDeviceSynchronize
  1.15%  3.5664ms       364  9.7970us     247ns  435.92us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
  0.86%  2.6475ms         4  661.88us  642.85us  682.42us  cuDeviceTotalMem
  0.09%  266.42us         4  66.603us  62.005us  77.380us  cuDeviceGetName
  0.01%  29.624us         1  29.624us  29.624us  29.624us  cudaMemset
  0.01%  19.147us         1  19.147us  19.147us  19.147us  cudaLaunch
  0.00%  4.8560us        12     404ns     248ns     988ns  cuDeviceGet
  0.00%  3.3390us         6     556ns     134ns  2.3510us  cudaSetupArgument
  0.00%  3.1190us         3  1.0390us     331ns  2.0780us  cuDeviceGetCount
  0.00%  1.1940us         1  1.1940us  1.1940us  1.1940us  cudaConfigureCall
$
```

We see that the kernel execution time is ~35ms in the non-shared case, and ~5.5ms in the shared case.  For this case I set `kc2=5`.  For the `kc2=3` case, performance gains will be less.

A few notes:

1. Your posted code was missing a semicolon on one line. I've added that and marked the line in my code.
2. I suspect you may have an indexing error on the "output" write to `outputArray`.  Your indexing is like this:

   ```
       int idx2 = (yIndex - kc2/2) * (width - kc2) + (xIndex - kc2/2);
   ```

   whereas I would have expected this:

   ```
       int idx2 = (yIndex - kc2/2) * width + (xIndex - kc2/2);
   ```

   however I haven't thought carefully about it, so I may be wrong here.
3. In the future, if you want help with a problem like this, I'd advise you to at least provide the level of complete code scaffolding and description that I have.  Provide a complete code that somebody else could immediately pick up and test, without having to write their own code.  Also define what platform you are on and what your performance measurement is.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer with the code I'll write after testing.